# Approximation of functions of 2 variables by multiplication of unidimensional functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, approximation, approximation-theory, linear-approximation

Let a function $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$, such that $f\in C^{1, 2}_b(\mathbb R^2)$ (that is $\partial_x f$, $\partial_y f$ and $\partial_{yy} f$ are continuous and bounded). Is it possible to approximate
$f$ and its derivatives by a sequence of functions
$$u_n(x, y)=\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}g_n(x)h_n(y),$$
where $g\in C_b^1(\mathbb R)$ and $h\in C^2_b(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: In which sense do you want to approximate? Uniformly? Pointwise? Locally uniformly?

Comment: I think pointwise will be sufficient.